# The difference between __call__ and other methods in Django middleware

Tags: django

Why do we use Django middleware predominantly for?

I’m relatively new to Django, so I’m trying to understand the difference between `__call__` and `process_view()` or `process_request()` methods. As I see, we use `__call__` before the request was filtered through every middleware in Django and to determine what method to use either `process_view()` or `process_request()`?

Comment: `__call__` is simply a dunder method in python for turning a class into a functor.

Answer (score 0):

Django middleware:

1. For: Common request/response tasks like authentication, logging, etc.
2. Works: By intercepting requests and responses.
3. Key methods:

   1. **__ call __**: Entry point, decides next step.
   2. **process_request**: Before view, e.g. authentication.
   3. **process_view**: For specific views and arguments.
   4. **process_response**: After view, e.g. add cookies.

Benefits: Cleaner code, modular tasks, reusable.